# Why does decimal.TryParse successfully parse something like 12,2,2,2

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

If I do the following:

```
string teststring = "12,2,2,2";
decimal testdecimal;
decimal.TryParse(teststring, out testdecimal)
```

This works and testdecimal ends up being 12222.

Shouldn't this reasonably/logically fail parsing? I was surprised to see that it worked and was curious as to what is the logic behind it that allows this.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)? `Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style. This means that white space and thousands separators are allowed but currency symbols are not.` Right above that, it tells you `,` is a culture-specific thousands separator symbol.

Comment: Would you expect `"1,234.56"` to parse as `1234.56`? Sure. If the comma were in the wrong spot, would you still expect it to parse as `1234.56`? Well, maybe. .NET is written so that this is the case, though I can't find it explicitly in the documentation. (related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your culture settings have `,` as the thousands separator. Since the thousands separator is purely for visual cues, and does not provide any significant information about the number, `decimal.TryParse` simply ignores thousands separators.

Comment: Then why doesn't `Int32.Parse("12,2,2,2")` succeed?

Comment: @dotnet Because thousands separators are not valid ever when parsing integers.

Comment: Right, but I was referring to the logic you presented: *thousands separator is purely for visual cues, and does not provide any significant information about the number*. Doesn't this logic apply to Int32 too?

Comment: @dotNET You could apply that logic. However, you tend to find thousands separators in currency, and not elsewhere. Which is why it just tends to be types used for currency that accept thousands separators. At least that's always how I've imagined the designers to have reasoned about this.

Answer (score 6):

By default, `TryParse()` allows group separators, which are `,` in your country.

To prevent this, pass a `NumberStyles` that does not include `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`.

The default is:

```
Number   = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign | AllowTrailingSign |
           AllowDecimalPoint | AllowThousands,
```

[Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/numberstyles.cs#56)

Answer (score 3):

It's because of digit group separators. When dealing with money types it's common to use a thousand separator. Decimal.TryParse considers the commas as thousand separator and parses it anyway. However, you have to note that this method is culture sensitive. For example if current culture is set to Turkish, TryParse won't be successful because in Turkish `,` is decimal point not thousand separator.

```
        var d1 = Decimal.Parse("1,23,25"); //parse is successful
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr");
        d1 = Decimal.Parse("1,23,45"); //throws exception
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the thousands separator for the Decimal parsing. If you want to disallow the thousands separators, you can just remove that flag, like this:

```
Decimal.Parse("12,2,2,2", NumberStyles.Number ^ NumberStyles.AllowThousands)
```

This will throw an InvalidFormatException